# Can I delete a row with a duplicate found in a higher row of another column

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

How can I delete a row from a list if a cell has a duplicate higher in the list? In the table below how could I delete rows 2 and 4 (Alex and Bob; Ted and Sam), but keep rows 1 and 3 (Bob and Alex; Sam and Ted)?

| Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | Alex |
| Alex | Bob |
| Sam | Ted |
| Ted | Sam |

[HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RbmRQxSJXqiuBst192btkdap2InyFRGXT1Q4EvbT_j4/edit#gid=0) is a sample sheet with what I'm talking about.

Comment: I would look at using index() with match() and reversing the match() to see if it comes back with a result - ie x with y & y with x then you can record one pair. Would have a go if you had supplied some data to play with.

Comment: Please edit your question after reading the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to using this forum. I updated the question to make it simpler and attached a sheet with data.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, assuming no version constraints as per your tag, you can add a helper column where you sort the entries for columns1 and 3; then use the `Remove Duplicates` tool selecting the `Sorted` column to consider

Sort Column formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,SORT(CHOOSECOLS(Table5[@[Name]:[Partner Name]],1,3),,,TRUE))
```

Note that I am using a table structure and structured references. One advantage is that when you enter this in the top cell of a column, it will populate the entire column

***Before:***
[image]

***Remove Duplicates tool***
[image]

***After:***
[image]

After this you can delete or hide the `Sorted` column.

Answer (score 0):

### Remove Duplicates

```
=LET(data,A2:D11,dupe_cols,{1;2;4},dlm,"@",
    s,BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(data,dupe_cols),LAMBDA(r,
        TEXTJOIN(dlm,,SORT(r,,,1)))),
INDEX(IF(data="","",data),XMATCH(UNIQUE(s),s),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(data))))
```

[image]

```
=LET(data,A3:C9,dupe_cols,{1;3},dlm,"@",
    s,BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(data,dupe_cols),LAMBDA(r,
        TEXTJOIN(dlm,,SORT(r,,,1)))),
INDEX(IF(data="","",data),XMATCH(UNIQUE(s),s),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(data))))
```

[image]